# instantiating enum of class passed as a parameter

Tags: java, generics, enums, compiler-warnings

i have a method:

```java
public Object instantiateAlmostAnyType(String stringToParse, Class<?> targetType) {
  ...
  if (targetType.isEnum())
    return Enum.valueOf((Class)targetType, stringToParse);
}
```

it works but i got compiler warnings. all for the `return` line:

```
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized
Enum is a raw type. References to generic type Enum should be parameterized
Type safety: The expression of type Class needs unchecked conversion to conform to Class
Type safety: Unchecked invocation valueOf(Class, String) of the generic method valueOf(Class, String) of type Enum
```

is there any way (except @suppressWarnings) to avoid warnings? any casts?

Comment: i updated my question with compiler warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

till now i haven't found a solution so i assume it's impossible. if someone gives me the answer i will accept it

Answer (score 5):

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> T instantiate(String stringToParse, Class<T> targetType) {
    ...
    return Enum.valueOf(targetType, stringToParse);
}
```

Now you check at compile time that the `Class` instance must be an `enum` type, and don't have to do any unsafe casting.

Comment: can't do that. this method also tries to instantiate other types, not only enums

Comment: Then you need to explain more about your actual problem.

Comment: i have a method that instantiates many different types based on their string representation and target type. it creates Integers, chars, BigDecimals etc. also enums. the problem is compiler don't like raw enums and class and don't like unchecked casts. and i don't like warnings and suppressing them

Comment: also there is no way to call this method. my input is of type: `Class<?> targetType` so when i call this method i have to do casts that produces same warnings